# Passing data from embedded TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` embedded in a `ViewController`. My `UITableView` has toggles. When one of these toggles are toggled I need my number on the `ViewController` to increase by 1. The issue I am having is not being able to get the text to change. I have supplied a screenshot to help better illustrate.

[image]

What I have tried doing is setting a variable `var colorViewController: ViewController?` in the `TableViewController` and then trying to set the text from there using `colorViewController?.displayNumber.text = screenCount` when toggling a toggle. `screenCount` is the variable that increasing as the toggles are toggled.

Comment: If you want to pass data from a viewcontroller to Previous viewcontroller, you should use any of these method: Singleton, Protocols or Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting your `colorViewController` variable?

You need to set it to the current instance of your ViewController in your ViewController's prepare for segue.

First, you'll need to give the embed segue an identifier. Select the segue in the storyboard and give it an identifier, say `ColorPickerTableViewControllerSegue`.

Then handle this segue in your ViewController (this is Swift 3 code):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ColorPickerTableViewControllerSegue" {
        if let colorPickerTableViewController = segue.destination as? ColorPickerTableViewController { 
            colorPickerTableViewController.colorViewController = self
        }
    }
}
```